# Nested translations in ngx-translate not working

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular14

I'm using `ngx-translate` to localize my `Angular 14` app.

Since I have a lot of keys, I wanted to organize them more cleanly inside my json files, and I've read that you can use nesting in a translation file like this:

```
{
  "license_page": {
    "title": "License activation",
    ...
  }
}
```

and then use it with dot notation, like this:

```
<h2>{{'license_page.title'| translate}}</h2>
```

However, in my app this is simply not working: while translations at the top level work correctly, the ones that are nested like the example above will simply print the translation key `license_page.title` instead of the value.

What am I missing here? Is there some configuration required for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I cleared the project (including the `node_modules` foldera) and rebuilt from scratch, it then started working.